# Shall I remove terraform lock file before running terraform init

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

I'm writing a small blog post regarding TF Provider migration that includes the following commands:

```
terraform state replace-provider foo/bar foo2/bar2

# Updating TF configuration file

terraform init
```

Shall I tell users to run

```
rm -rf .terraform/                          
rm .terraform.lock.hcl
```

before running

```
terraform init
```

Comment: No, you should not tell them to remove anything created by terraform. In fact, for the dependency lock file, it is recommended to be stored in your version control repository, if you are using one. You can read more about it here: https://www.terraform.io/language/files/dependency-lock

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `terraform state replace-provider` command requires an initialized backend and so it will not work unless `terraform init` were run first.

The `.terraform` directory contains some transient working directory state that Terraform should typically be able to reproduce if needed, but deleting it does mean that any module dependencies that don't have exact version constraints could potentially select a different version when installed again, that command-line-specified backend configuration arguments will be lost, and that the currently-selected workspace will be reset back to the default.

Therefore I would not suggest just casually recommending that users remove that directory, unless you're able to explain the potential consequences of doing so.

---

`.terraform.lock.hcl` is [the dependency lock file](https://www.terraform.io/language/files/dependency-lock) and should be treated as part of the configuration, even though `terraform init` automatically updates it, since its purpose is to remember between runs which version of each provider was selected. That file should typically be kept under version control once created.

Along with saving a record of which version was selected for each provider, the dependency lock file also provides a "trust on first use" methodology for Terraform providers, by saving the checksums of the providers so that if you take any steps to verify the providers you installed are trustworthy then you can be sure that Terraform will not allow any package with a different checksum unless you specifically opt to upgrade using `terraform init -upgrade`.

In that case, removing `.terraform.lock.hcl` would defeat that mechanism by removing the record of the original checksum, meaning there would be no guarantee that `terraform init` would install the same package as before.